# Question on calculating $H_*(X).$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Let $C$ be the circle on the torus $T$ which is the image of the line $px = qy$ under the covering map $\mathbb R^2 \longrightarrow T$ (this identifies $T = S^1 \times S^1$ and sends $(a,b)$ to their image modulo $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$). Let $X = T/C$ the quotient space obtained by identifying $C$ to a point. Calculate $H_*(X).$

I think I need to somehow use the homology of the long exact sequence of $$\cdots \longrightarrow H_n (C) \longrightarrow H_n (T) \longrightarrow H_n(X) \longrightarrow H_{n-1} (C) \longrightarrow H_{n-1} (T) \longrightarrow \cdots$$

Using that it is easy to see that $H_n (X) = 0,$ for $n \geq 3$ and $H_0(X) = \mathbb Z.$ To compute $H_1(X)$ and $H_2(X)$ the only map we need to figure out is $\mathbb Z \cong H_1(C) \longrightarrow H_1(T) \cong \mathbb Z^2.$ But I am unable to figure it out properly. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

A generator for $H_1(C)$ is the loop traveling along $C$ once. And generators for $H_1(T)$ are the loops going around $T$ in the longitudinal and meridional directions. So we're asking how many times $C$ goes around $T$ in those directions.

Let's assume that $p$ and $q$ are integers such that $\frac{p}{q}$ is a reduced fraction. In $\Bbb{R}^2$, the line $y = \frac{p}{q}x$ passes through $(0,0)$ and $(q,p)$ and no other integer points in between these two.
Thus, the circle $C$ can be seen as the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(q,p)$. The fact that this line travels $p$ units vertically and $q$ units horizontally is saying that $C$ travels around $T$ in the meridional direction $p$ times and in the longitudinal direction $q$ times.

So I think the map is the one which sends $1 \in \Bbb{Z}$ to $(p,q) \in \Bbb{Z}^2$.